# URL parameters to file

Tags: php

how to create and write a file using url parameters

for example:
web.com/index.php?name=test.txt?input=halloworld

file name should be test.txt and its content must be halloworld.

this is what i have so far

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{

    $File = $_GET['name']; 
    $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
    $Data =  $_GET['input']; 
    fwrite($Handle, $Data);
    fclose($Handle); 
}
```

file output = test.txt?input=halloworld which is wrong

thank you.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, as all sorts of different files on your machine can be written to.  Try using file IDs, or at least implement a whitelist of files that are allowed to be written to.

Comment: Im not quite sure if i have understood you right. Im using the script to generate xml files on a server in the same directory. so what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: What if I pass `web.com/index.php?name=evil.php&input=<?php exec('rm -rf /');` (obviously urlencoded) and then I call `web.com/evil.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in using ? instead of & in your url, it should be `web.com/index.php?name=test.txt&input=halloworld`

That said you should **never** do things like this, because it's extremely dangerous. In that way you're exposing your server to any kind of attacks or defacing. An attacker could easily write a php file on your webserver and take control of it.

Keep that in mind.

Edit: I wrote it in question comment, but I rewrite it here, what if an attacker invoke your script with this parameters:

```
web.com/index.php?name=evil.php&input=<?php exec('rm -rf /');
```

and then request the url

```
web.com/evil.php
```

Your filesystem will be wiped out (if the user has privileges to do that). Other kind of attacks could be more subtle, one could inject a [php shell](http://www.google.it/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20shell) in your server, and so on.

Comment: some perspective please! using a chainsaw to brush your teeth is extremely dangerous. This is just dumb :)

Answer (score 1):

web.com/index.php?name=test.txt?input=halloworld is not a correct query string. consider:

```
web.com/index.php?name=test.txt&input=halloworld
```